# How to do an update my TreeView in wpf?

Tags: wpf, treeview

Good evening.
I started studying the technology - wpf in c#
Now I stopped at the section - work with treeview
I want to add a new node in my treeview in my task.

I have a form and button on this form:

```
...
<Button Name="btn1" Click="ShowForWriteAdrBookName" Content="TestBtn"/>
...
```

When you run the program on my form is loaded UserControl, which have treeview:

```
...
<TreeView Name="treeView1"></TreeView>
...
```

When I press the

```
...
<Grid>
        <Label Name="Label1" Content="Имя адресной книги:" Margin="0,20,0,0"></Label>
        <TextBox Name="TextBox1" Width="200" Height="30" Margin="90,-40,0,0"></TextBox>
        <Button Content="Ок" Width="80" Height="30" Margin="0,50,0,0" Click="GetAdrBookName"></Button>
        <Button Content="Отмена" Width="80" Height="30" Margin="200,50,0,0" Click="MyExit"></Button>
</Grid>
...
```

After entering text in the TextBox I click OK. Function is called:

```
...
public void GetAdrBookName(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
        {
            if (String.Compare(TextBox1.Text.ToString(), "") != 0)
            {
                adrName = TextBox1.Text.ToString().Trim();
                this.Close();
                CreateAdrBook(adrName);
            }
            else 
            {
                ...
            }
        }
...
```

In this function, I read information from textbox. And then call another function:

```
...
public void CreateAdrBook(string adrNameFromTextBox1)
        {
            mylist.Add(adrNameFromTextBox1);
            int s = mylist.Count;
            TreeView();
    }
...
```

In this function, I add getting information from my textbox to my collection:

```
...
ObservableCollection<string> mylist = new ObservableCollection<string>() 
        { 
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
        };
...
```

After I added more information in my collection, I add this information to my TreeView in function:

```
...
void TreeView()
        {
            foreach (var drive in mylist)
            {
                TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
                item.Tag = drive;
                item.Header = drive.ToString();
                item.Items.Add("*");
                treeView1.Items.Add(item);
                treeView1.Items.Refresh();
                treeView1.UpdateLayout();

            }
        }
...
```

**Question:**
How to do an update my TreeView after adding in this TreeView a new element?
Thank you!

Comment: Please use Bindings to update your TreeView collection. You can set the ItemsSource of the treeview to your collection.

Comment: @Jack, thanks for your answer!
Sorry, but can you tell me about Bindings and ItemsSource more? or give me example of how to use them, please?